# doxygen how to reference documentation from within param

Tags: doxygen, ref

I have a simple snippet with doxygen code in a header file for a function.

```
@param info A reference to a structure of type 
@ref verify_info which will be filled in.
Upon return the contents of this structure are defined
if and only if the verify function completes successfully
as indicated by the ec parameter.
```

The problem is that the @ref doesn't link to the type verify_info as it should.  This linkage works fine outside of the paragraph.  In fact, even automatic linking works.  But within the scope of the @param explanation this doesn't work.  Am I missing something or is this not meant to work.  If it's the latter, how can I work around it.

Comment: Didn't check but did you try #verify_info instead of \ref verify_info?

Comment: LOL - I thought I had checked every other possibility but I hadn't checked this so I did just now.  It was displayed as  #verify_info.  Also doxygen emitted an warning message: warning: explicit link request to 'verify_info' could not be resolved.  This is interesting since it means that it's actually recognizing the link request but failing to implement it.  I forgot to mention that the original @ref verify_info results in a display of  |6|verify_info - displayed in red color.  Sooooo something is going on bug damned if I can make this work!  Thanks for your help

Comment: Is verify_info the full name you are looking for or is it a class member or something alike?

Comment: it's the name of a struct.  Note that it links perfectly if it's outside the param description.  So I can't help but think that there is some extra "rule" about having links in param descriptions.  But I can't imagine what that might be and if there's a way to work around it.

Comment: Works for me, struct { int a; } str; and I refer to #str

Comment: Hmmm - I'm using struct verify_info {}.  That is I'm referring to the name of the structure not the name of the data itself.  Also are you using #str inside of a param paragraph?  Note that this is the place where mine if failing.  for example void f(verify_info & vi) where &vi is being documented.
{}.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144143/discussion-between-robert-ramey-and-albert).

Comment: I posted some code in the chat.

Comment: Added a question to the discussion (will check it irregular)

Comment: I tracked this down.  I've been working on a project which used doxygen.  But it was also using xslt to massage the Doxygen output and that was causing the problem.  So doxygen is off the hook.  Thanks for your help.  Without that, I might not have looked in the right place.